# Emacs: Default binary to run with M-x ansi-term

Tags: emacs, zsh, ansi-term

Is there a way to have Emacs to prompt by default for a binary of my choice when running `M-x ansi-term`. It always asks me for `/bin/zsh` but I have a new installation of `zsh` in a different path.

Alternatively, it would be great to have Emacs to just run the binary I want when I type `M-x my-ansi-term`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of ways to specify the default shell:

- Set the variable `explicit-shell-file-name`.  For example, in your `.emacs`: `(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")`
- Set the environment variable `ESHELL`
- Set the environment variable `SHELL`

Answer (score 3):

> Alternatively, it would be great to have Emacs to just run the binary I want when I type M-x my-ansi-term

See [Remote ssh connection from within Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495432/remote-ssh-connection-from-within-emacs/10536794#10536794).