# Emacs: Keyboard shortcut to run ansi-term with a specific shell

Tags: emacs

I would like to associate a keyboard binding in Emacs (e.g. <kbd>C-c a</kbd>) that automatically starts an ansi-term window with a shell that I have pre-specified in my `.emacs` file (without prompting anything)

For reference, there are two threads in StackOverflow that address similar problems:

- [Remote ssh connection from within Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495432/remote-ssh-connection-from-within-emacs/10536794#10536794)
- [Emacs: Default binary to run with M-x ansi-term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679743/emacs-default-binary-to-run-with-m-x-ansi-term)

but it isn't obvious to me how to combine the ideas in those threads to get an answer to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") '(lambda ()  (interactive) (ansi-term "/bin/zsh")))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [multi-term](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.fr/2010/06/console-apps-in-emacs-with-multi-term.html). As its name implies, it lets you deal with multiple term using ansi-term.

Here is a small configuration:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(eval-after-load "multi-term"
                 '(setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash"
                   term-unbind-key-list '("C-x"
                                          "C-h"
                                          "M-x"
                                          "C-z")
                   term-term-name "xterm-256color"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'multi-term-next)
```

My whole configuration for multi-term is
[here](https://github.com/daimrod/Emacs-config/blob/master/config-multi-term.el)
(`compilation-shell-minor-mode` is really nice).