# How to open remote shell in Emacs

Tags: shell, emacs

I was wondering if one can open shell of machines accessible by ssh. If I do M-x remote shell, I am taken to the shell on the current machine. In my case, I run emacs over windows XP and therefore it takes me to shell of windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote ssh connection from within Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495432/remote-ssh-connection-from-within-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if [ssh.el](http://www.splode.com/~friedman/software/emacs-lisp/src/ssh.el) works for you?