# eterm-color: Unknown terminal type

Tags: unix, emacs, terminal, emacs24, ansi-term

In an `ansi-term` terminal in Emacs, when I ssh to a specific remote host, the terminal is not recognized properly, and I get the error:

```
'eterm-color': unknown terminal type.
```

I added `export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo` to `.bashrc` on the remote machine, and I have tried the following on the remote machine:

```
cp -r /usr/share/emacs/21.4/etc/e ~/.terminfo
```

Just in case, I also tried copying over my own local copy of `/etc/e` (Emacs 24.3) to `~/.terminfo` on the remote machine.

Also, in case it matters, if I try `infocmp` on the remote machine, I get:

```
>infocmp
infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file /usr/share/terminfo/e/eterm-color.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try the solution given [here](http://superuser.com/questions/431922/tmux-and-screen-256-term-not-supported-on-remote-hosts) Run `infocmp` on the local system, and then `tic` on the remote host. Just change `screen-256color` by `eterm-color`

Comment: May be interesting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91977/whats-the-right-value-of-term-for-emacs-ansi-term-especially-if-eterm-color/93044#93044

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does seem that you've seen the following information already, so it might not help, but it's probably worth reiterating.

The [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints) explains that you should copy (or symlink) the `eterm-color` and `eterm-color.ti` files from the `/usr/share/emacs/xx.x/etc/e` directory on your local system to the `~/.terminfo/e/` directory (or alternatively, system-wide at `/usr/share/terminfo/e/`).

Of course you can also do likewise on any remote host you need to connect to.

On Debian-based systems you administer, you can `apt-get install ncurses-term`, which includes `/usr/share/terminfo/e/eterm-color`.

With regard to the details in the question, note that if you didn't *already* have a `~/.terminfo` directory then `cp -r /usr/share/emacs/21.4/etc/e ~/.terminfo` would not do what you intended it to do. It's not clear whether or not that was the case, but it may explain why it didn't work? You need the eterm-color files under a `~/.terminfo/e/` directory; not directly in `~/.terminfo/`.

(n.b. Personally I always just install `ncurses-term`, so I can't vouch directly for the `~/.terminfo` approach.)

Comment: Thanks -- After manually building `ncurses` from source on the remote machine (with `--fPIC` for Zsh to work), copying my local `eterm-color` and `eterm-color.ti` to the `~/.terminfo/e/` folder on the remote machine , AND removing statements in my shell init files that tried to set/export the env. variable `TERM` ... this FINALLY worked!

Comment: For future reference, building `ncurses` was **not** enough since  it did **not** install `terminfo` files for `eterm`. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I had to copy these two files from my **local** Emacs installation to the **remote** `~/.terminfo/e` folder.

Comment: Had a vm in a gce environment that was doing this while using multi-term to ssh into the instance. apt-get installing ncurses fixed it all up.

Comment: eterm-color has been part of ncurses terminal database since 2008, so OP's problems installing it are more likely due to some misconfiguration, e.g., `$TERMINFO` mis-set, and copying a file from Emacs won't improve matters.