# Emacs: How to read command help just as one would read Man pages?

Tags: emacs

It's nice to run `M-x man foo` for command `foo` within `Emacs`. It's then possible to navigate easily within the man page and to find details quickly.

When the help of a command (such as `git`) produces limited output, one can just use a terminal instead of emacs.

But occasionally, a command (such as `aws help`—run in a terminal) produces extensive output. Yet the output is not compatible with the emacs Man mode. An option is to use M-x shell within emacs, but that will not display the page at once. It will report "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" and require pressing a key endlessly until the complete help appears, or, for Emacs 25, "Could not find executable named 'groff'".

What is a good way to read long manual pages produced by commands within emacs?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact problem a few days ago.

Type escape + ! then type (for example) “aws ec2 help”. This brings the help text into a new buffer called *Shell Command Output*, with all of the control-h characters, etc.

Switch to the new buffer with control-x then lowercase ‘o’ (for other buffer)

Type escape + lowercase ‘x’ to run an emacs function, then type ‘man’ and hit Enter. It will prompt for man page entry and default to EC2, just hit Enter. In my case, it displays an error in the status line, “error in process sentinel: Can’t find the EC2 manpage”.

However, the “man page” functions are now available, so now (in that buffer)you can type escape + x and run the function Man-fontify-manpage. The page should now look like a nice man page with bold, etc.

You can then rename the buffer (escape + x then something like *ec2*) so the buffer isn’t replaced if you run another shell command.

Comment: in evil mode, I type `:!man aws help` then `M-x Man-fontify-manpage`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I you just want the output in a buffer, you can simply use:
<kbd>M-!</kbd> `aws help` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: That should do it, but I get "D^HDE^HES^HSC^HCR^HRI^HIP^HPT^HTI^HIO^HON^HN" instead of "DESCRIPTION". The mode is fundamental-mode. That seems to be the problem, since the same kind of output appears when typing 'man ls'. Now the question is (or may be) how to force man mode on a shell output page.

Comment: Oh, it's using overtyping for bold text. I don't get that on my system. I guess that's a terminal issue, but I'm not sure what the correct solution is offhand. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091145/324105

Comment: After copying /Applications/Emacs-24.4.app/Contents/Resources/etc/e/ to ~/.terminfo, the problem persists.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can provide the answer. The only other approach I can suggest right now is to use `M-x ansi-term` to run the commands (from a shell) in a proper terminal emulator. You can use `C-c C-j` to change to `term-line-mode`, which will let you navigate the buffer using regular Emacs commands (and `C-c C-k` to change back to `term-char-mode`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output in a shell buffer, you can do `git help commit | cat` (so no more "terminal is not fully functional").

Probably you can do `M-! aws help | cat RET` also. I do not have aws, but hopefully the piping will remove the escape characters if aws output formatting is done right.  You should try also `TERM=dumb aws help`.  Any command should know better than using fancy output when TERM is set to dumb. If aws is dumb that way itself, you could pipe its output to something that filters out control characters -- try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

For forcing man mode in an arbitrary buffer, `M-x Man-mode` (yes, uppercase).  I am not sure if that will play nice with aws's output.

By the way, for git I suppose you know you can do `man git-commit` (or man git-any_git_command, in general), so you have a nice alternative to `git help` when using emacs (output of help and man page is the same).

Comment: After M-! aws help | cat RET I read "Use _^Ha_^Hw_^Hs _^Hc_^Ho_^Hm_^Hm_^Ha_^Hn_^Hd _^Hh_^He_^Hl_^Hp for information on a specific command."