# What does yarn use for updating the terminal line? It does not work in an emacs shell. It seems to be updating but not always in an informative way

Tags: emacs, hadoop-yarn

We have a lot of yarn stuff. I use emacs. The install stuff that updates the terminal output line does not work and just keeps repeating strings in the emacs shell. Other progress tools like pv and my own ruby and shell scripts that rewrite the line work fine. What is yarn doing for the updates? And why? Anything I can do to turn it off? Anything I can do to fix it in the emacs shell buffer? Yarn 1.22.4.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt it's using some terminal escape codes to manipulate the display.

`M-x shell` (and `comint` generally) is more or less a dumb terminal, so anything relying on more capable terminals will not work well.  Use `M-x term` to get a proper terminal emulator, suitable for such programs.

Comment: Many packages and even my scripts use terminal escape codes, and work fine in shell. I have tried term and it has more issues overall, not less. I am interested in finding out what terminal escape codes or what tool yarn uses to update the line.

Comment: If you're having more problems with output in `term` than with `shell` then maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/22083177/324105 will help.

Comment: You can pipe yarn's output to `cat -v` to better see what it's outputting.

Comment: Tried that a long time ago. Yarn somehow detects and doesn't do any special characters.