# Elisp interactive function with input history

Tags: emacs, elisp

there is a bunch of interactive functions which take string input as an argument:

```
(defun zb/run-cmd-X (arg1 argN)
  (interactive "Marg1: Marg2: ")
  ;;; some logic
```

How to make each of such functions `zb/run-cmd-1`..`zb/run-cmd-N` have **own** independent history of input arguments `arg1...argN`? And it would be perfect if this history was persistent between Emacs launches (ideally somewhere in an external file; for sync).

Is there any ready solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to read the documentation for `read-from-minibuffer` and `completing-read` regarding the `HIST` argument which each of those functions accepts. There are other functions with history support of course, but these two are the standard/basic options.

Persistence is provided for by the `savehist` library, which writes to the file in `savehist-file` (which by default is `~/.emacs.d/history`, but the old `~/.emacs-history` will be used instead if that file exists -- in which case you might want to rename it to the modern preferred path).

Here's an example:

```el
(defvar my-ssh-history nil)

(eval-after-load "savehist"
  '(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'my-ssh-history))

(defun my-ssh (args)
  "Connect to a remote host by SSH."
  (interactive
   (list (read-from-minibuffer "ssh " nil nil nil 'my-ssh-history)))
  (let* ((switches (split-string-and-unquote args))
         (name (concat "ssh " args))
         (termbuf (apply 'make-term name "ssh" nil switches)))
    (set-buffer termbuf)
    (term-mode)
    (term-char-mode)
    (switch-to-buffer termbuf)))

(savehist-mode 1)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that for each argument of each function I have to define an independent variable for history? Doesn't the author finally come to amount-of-functions * amount-of-input-args variables?

Comment: If it's generated code, then the whole thing could be wrapped up in a macro, or the history var could be let-bound in the interactive call to point into a different structure which holds all histories. It's not clear to me what the exact requirement actually was, but the solution can certainly be constructed based on this approach.

Comment: @phils, it is not generated code but the functions looks very similar: take same input arguments, pass them to an external application and show an output; so macro is not the way I think. But I have understand the general idea, so everything beside could be built over this example. The only problem I see that `read-from-minibuffer` might not work with non-string arguments (e.g. regions/buffers).