# vi editing crashes within the shell-mode of emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, vi

Steps to reproduce this:

1. open emacs
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell` RET
3. `vi tmpfile` RET

Then you'll see the vi interface is a mess. To quit this, try to blind input `:q!` or just close the shell buffer.

The reason I use "vi" within emacs is that I use emacs shell-mode heavily and sometimes I ssh to another host within it. On the remote host, i have a reason to use "vi" when i need to edit some file and emacs is absent there.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: But `emacs` has features for remote editing.... See [tramp](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000983.html)

Comment: Thanks for introducing me "tramp". In my case, the major requirement is to work on remote hosts over ssh and sometimes have a need to edit files there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that a proper terminal emulator is necessary for anything like that.

Emacs has one, happily. Try running <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ansi-term`. You can run a shell within that (the default option) and then ssh to the remote host as you were in shell mode.

(If you didn't need to change hosts then you could run `vi` directly, instead of a shell.)

You might also find [Remote ssh connection from within Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495432/remote-ssh-connection-from-within-emacs/10536794#10536794) useful.

You will undoubtedly want to stick to `char-mode` in the terminal when using vi.
See: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Terminal emulator` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @phils, it's really helpful, this problem had bothered me a long time.

Comment: The reference link is also helpful, i learnt staff from that. Yes, i would use the default char-mode when using vi, sometimes, line-mode is preferred, C-c C-o is one of my favors.